# 3D Maze solving with BFS. How to get a full shortest path to the end point if found in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to implement the BFS algorithm to check if a goal is reachable in a 3D maze given a starting position. The maze was imported from a txt file. My solution seems to find the goal however I am not able to display just the path that was taken. My issue: I am able to find the goal but I have no idea how to get the shortest path and print it out. I was thinking about using parents/children concept but I am not sure whether it works.
I hope I can finally print out the path like this: (from start point to end point)

```
1 3 1
1 3 2
2 3 3
```

This is my code:

I use struct to store informations from txt file.

```
struct Maze
{
    int x,y,z; //dimensions
    int sx,sy,sz;//start point
    int ex,ey,ez;//exit point
    int grids; //number of grids in the maze where are actions available
    vector<vector<int> > glist;
    vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > > gpoint; // list of (x,y,z) accessible
};
void BFS(Maze &maze,vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > > result){
    bool reach_end = false;
    int xx,yy,zz;                               
    int j=0;
    int move_count = 0;
    int nodes_left_in_layer = 1;
    int nodes_in_next_layer = 0;
    queue<int> xq,yq,zq;
    xq.push(maze.sx);yq.push(maze.sy);zq.push(maze.sz);
    

    vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > > visited(maze.grids);
    visited.push_back(make_pair(xx, make_pair(yy, zz)));
    result.push_back(make_pair(xx, make_pair(yy, zz)));

    while(!xq.empty()){
        int xfront = xq.front();int yfront = yq.front();int zfront = zq.front();
        xq.pop();yq.pop();zq.pop();
        
        if(xfront==maze.ex && yfront==maze.ey && zfront==maze.ez){
            reach_end = true;
            cout << "reach end!" <<endl;
            break;
        }
        int index=0;
        index = getindex(maze,xfront,yfront,zfront);
    
        
        //EXPLORE NEIGHBORS
        for(j=0;j<maze.glist[index].size()-3;j++){
        
            int action = maze.glist[index][3+j];
            
            xx = xfront+dx[action-1];    // dx,dy,dz are lists of actions. 
            yy = yfront+dy[action-1];
            zz = zfront+dz[action-1];
            auto p2 = make_pair(xx,make_pair(yy,zz));
        
            //skip bounds
            if(xx<0 || yy<0 || zz<0){}
            else if(xx >= maze.x || yy>= maze.y || zz >= maze.z){}
            else if(find(visited.begin(),visited.end(),p2)!=visited.end()){
                cout << "Visited: "<<xx <<yy<<zz<<endl;
            }
            else if(find(maze.gpoint.begin(),maze.gpoint.end(),p2)!=maze.gpoint.end()){
            
                int index2 = getindex(maze,xx,yy,zz);
                xq.push(xx);yq.push(yy);zq.push(zz);
                visited.push_back(p2);
                nodes_in_next_layer++;
            }else{
                cout<<"Not in glist!! "<<endl;
            }
        
        }
  
        nodes_left_in_layer--;
        if(nodes_left_in_layer==0){
            nodes_left_in_layer = nodes_in_next_layer;
            nodes_in_next_layer=0;
            move_count++;
        }
    
    
    }
    if(reach_end){
    
        cout<< "move_count: " <<move_count<<endl;
        cout << "nodes_left_in_layer: " <<nodes_left_in_layer<<endl;
        cout << "nodes_in_next_layer: " <<nodes_in_next_layer<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<< "xxxFAILxxx " <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the exact issue you are having? Does your code work, does it not? Which part doesn't work? What have you tried?
Your question will gain a lot more traction if you have a [example] and a very focused question.

Comment: @NathanWride Hi! My issue is that I am able to find the goal but I have no idea how to get the shortest path and print it out. I was thinking about using parents/children concept but I am not sure whether it works. Sorry for making confusion.

Comment: You've got the basic idea in here, you are iterating through neighbouring cells and adding them to a list of searched cells. What you need to do next is keep track of a cells "score" 
 (which in the simplest solution is the score of the previous cell plus one), and once you have found the goal you need to then work backwards through your list (starting from the goal) to find which neighbouring cell has the next smallest value. When you are finished you will have a list of cells starting at the goal and ending at the start and it will be the shortest path.

Comment: I would recommend reading more on [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dijkstras-short-path-finder/) and [A*](https://brilliant.org/wiki/a-star-search/)

Answer (score 2):

There 2 common ways:

1. You remember the distance of every visited cell from the start, and then when you find the end you walk back to the start, along the path that decreases distance with every step.  This method is memory-efficient when you can use a bit-packed representation for visited vertexes, since you only need to remember the lowest 2 bits of the distance.  This doesn't apply easily to you.
2. You directly remember the predecessor of every visited cell, and when you find the end you just follow all those links back to the start.

You should probably use method (2).

I suggest you replace your `visited` vector, which is currently very inefficient, with a `std::unordered_map` that maps each visited vertex to the index of its predecessor.